# Rails not acessing fields values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Model

```
class Register < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor   :code
belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :register
end
```

Controller

```
def index
    @registers = Register.all
end
```

View

```
 <p> All Registers </p>
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td> User </td>
 <td> Point </td>
 </tr>
 <% @registers.each do |u| %>
 <tr>
 <td> <%= u.user.name %> </td>
 <td> <%= u.hour %> </td>
 </tr>
 <% end %>
 </table>
```

it onlys display Name instead of the field value
and the console is giving me this error

```
no such column: users.register_id: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."register_id" = ? LIMIT 1
```

Comment: looks more like the `registers` table should have a `user_id` column than the other way around. 
Your `@user` assignment in the controller looks totally wrong. What are you trying to achieve? How does that even work?

Comment: Display all register and their user names

Comment: You should then be trying to do something like:
`<% @registers.each do |u| %>
...
<%= u.user.name %> 
<%= u.hour %>
`

Comment: I tried and the system returns     it undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 2):

First Add user_id to registers table.

Update your index action to below.

```
def index
    @registers = Register.all
end
```

and view code to following.

```
<% @registers.each do |u| %> 
  <%= u.user.name %> 
  <%= u.hour %>
<% end %>
```

Update you user model to below.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :registers
end
```

Comment: I can display u.user_id but I cant acess u.user.name

Comment: Hey, In rails console could you please run the command "Register.first.user.name" once and see what output you get.

Comment: Register Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "registers".* FROM "registers"  ORDER BY "registers"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
 from (irb):1

Comment: I have updated my answer update your user model. it should be                   "has_many :registers" not  "has_many :register".

Answer (score 0):

To add to `@Dheeresha`'s great answer, you need to also appreciate that you actually have to associate the two objects. To do this, you can use the following (as a test):

```
$ rails c
$ user     = User.first
$ register = Register.first

$ user.registers << register
```

This will ensure you have at least one `register` in the `user.registers` collection. The way to ensure this is not an issue in production / view is to use the [`.try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) method:

```
<% @registers.each do |u| %> 
  <%= u.user.try(:name) %> 
  <%= u.hour %>
<% end %>
```

The only reason you wouldn't be able to access the `user` object would be that it's not associated in `ActiveRecord`. This issue in itself could be caused by not having the associations defined correctly (as `@Dheeresha` pointed out), or not associating the objects (as I've mentioned).

--

Your models should look like:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :registers
end

#app/models/register.rb
class Register < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```